# Исключить конкретное число из регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Путем регулярного выражения я пытаюсь извлечь из письма html-формата полученный 6-ти значный код. 
Делаю я это путем `\d{6}`
Это извлекает все числа из письма с 6-ю элементами, но проблема в том, что в коде письма есть повторяющееся несколько раз число "333333". 
Как я могу извлечь нужный мне код, срезав эти тройки? 
Пытался с помощью `\d{6}[^3333333]` и все в таком роде - безрезультатно. С регулярными выражениями до этого не сталкивался.

Comment: `(?!333333)\d{6}` или ``(?!3{6})\d{6}`` или ``\b(?!3{6})\d{6}\b``

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если необходимо найти все 6-значные числа независимо от контекста, и при этом исключить совпадения конкретного 6-значного числа, можно использовать

```
(?!333333)\d{6}
```

В данном случае, этот шаблон можно сократить до `(?!3{6})\d{6}`. См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/VwutWp/1). `(?!333333)` - отрицающий (негативный) блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который исключает совпадение, если сразу после текущей позиции есть подстрока `333333`. `3{6}` находит цифру `3` шесть раз подряд.

Если необходимо извлечь числа как целые слова, используйте границы слова, `\b`:

```
\b(?!333333\b)\d{6}\b
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/VwutWp/2). Первый `\b` требует наличия начала строки или буквы/цифры/`_` сразу перед совпадением, а второй `\b` требует наличия конца строки или буквы/цифры/`_` сразу после совпадения.

Если необходимо найти только такие числа, с обеих сторон которых могут находиться любые символы, кроме цифр, используйте

```
(?<!\d)(?!333333(?!\d))\d{6}(?!\d)
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/VwutWp/3). `(?<!\d)` требует отсутствия цифры сразу перед совпадением, а `(?!\d)` требует отсутствия цифры сразу после совпадения.